# How do i ask paincomponent to draw things from other methods or classes

Tags: java

i want to ask paintcomponent from the TestGraphics class to draw a line, the way i'm doing it is just giving me a NullPointer Exception, i would be thankful for you if you could tell me how i could this

TestGraphics class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestGraphics extends JPanel {
    
    
    public JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
            
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawLine(120, 234, 23, 43);
            
        }
    };
    
}
```

Main class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    
    static int width = 600;
    static int height = 800;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        TestGraphics p = new TestGraphics();
        
        // draw Line
        p.panel.getGraphics().drawLine(123, 23, 43, 21);
        
        
        frame.add(p.panel);
        
        
        frame.setSize(height, width);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and show which line causes the error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at me.ajjy.testlife.Main.main(Main.java:21)

Comment: NullPointer means your program is attempting to access an object with a reference, and the value of that reference is NULL. It happens at runtime. Which part of your code in particular gives the error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at me.ajjy.testlife.Main.main(Main.java:21)

Comment: p.panel.getGraphics().drawLine(123, 23, 43, 21); its that line

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the full stack trace and which line causes the error. My apologies for not being clear that I was asking for an edit instead of a comment.

Comment: You should not attempt to draw a line outside of `paintComponent()`. For now just remove `p.panel.getGraphics().drawLine(123, 23, 43, 21);`. What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: its hard to explain but i'll do my best, eventually i'll make constructors for lines, rectangles, triangles etc. i want to give paintcomponent some x and y values to draw said lines and rectangles and triangles, thats the best i could explain, sorry if this doesn't make sense, so basically i make java objects then draw them to paintcomponent

Comment: if i can't do it like this i would love to hear other ways that i could do this

Comment: Many incorrect assumptions here.  Please read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/.

Comment: thank you so much, i cant describe how much i'm thankful, i have been struggling for days

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a new TestGraphics object, not to call " p.panel.getGraphics().drawLine(123, 23, 43, 21);". Here are the simple fixs:

TestGraphics.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestGraphics extends JPanel {
    
        public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
            
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawLine(120, 234, 23, 43);
            
        }
  
    }
```

and Main.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    
    static int width = 600;
    static int height = 800;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        TestGraphics p = new TestGraphics();
        
        // draw Line
        frame.add(p);
        frame.setSize(height, width);
        frame.setVisible(true);
           
    }
   
}
```

Here are small example: https://repl.it/repls/ExtrovertedSoulfulClients

Comment: @YoushaRaza Now you can draw any thing with your TestGraphics class. If you want to add the parameters to your drawing, let add another constructer like :
private int x1, y1, x2, y2;
  public TestGraphics(int _x1, int _y1, int _x2, int _y2) {
    x1 = _x1;
    x2 = _x2;
    y1 = _y1;
    y2 = _y2;
  }
And of course If this answer solved your question let verify it. :))))

Comment: God bless you answered my problem, i'm so thankful for you right now

Answer (score 0):

To fix the immediately problem, you need to remove the line

```
        p.panel.getGraphics().drawLine(123, 23, 43, 21);
```

because you are not allowed to call `drawLine()` outside of `paintComponent()`.

Change

```
        frame.add(p.panel);
```

to

```
        frame.add(p);
```

and

```
public class TestGraphics extends JPanel {
    
    
    public JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
            
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawLine(120, 234, 23, 43);
            
        }
    };
    
}
```

to

```
public class TestGraphics extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawLine(120, 234, 23, 43);
    }
}
```

Since `TestGraphics` already extends `JPanel`, you can add the `p` instance directly to the `JFrame` and override `paintComponent()` directly instead of creating an anonymous `JPanel` class.

From comments:

> eventually i'll make constructors for lines, rectangles, triangles etc. i want to give paintcomponent some x and y values to draw said lines and rectangles and triangles

More specifically, you should make classes that represent each of these geometric objects. Each class should have a `void paint(Graphics g)` method. In fact, you should consider making an interface or abstract class `GeometricObject` with this method that you can call from your panel's `paintComponent(). Your` GraphicsTest`class can keep a`List`and call`paint(g)`on each of them from its`paintComponent()`.

There will be a lot to learn about here: abstract classes, interfaces, lists, and loops, just to name a few. Good luck!

Comment: oh god thank you so much, i've been trying to brainstorm how i could do this for weeks, i cant describe how much i'm thankful, thank god you came here

Comment: well i have a problem now, i don't know what to use, i know how to use abstract classes and interfaces but i don't know which is going to be best for what i'm doing

Comment: @YoushaRaza Pick one. They are about equivalent for your purposes. In fact, implement first with one and then with the other. This will give you an opportunity to learn more about the differences.

Comment: by the way edit what you said previously, everything you at the end wrote looks wrong, but still thank you for the advice